# update network and subnet quota during Openstack installation

Tags: openstack

The default values are 10 which are not enough for our project.

is there a way to modify the network and subnet quota with Openstack APIs and shell script?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to follow: http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide-admin/content/cli_set_quotas.html

In brief (repeating one of the examples in the link above)

```
 neutron quota-update --tenant_id {your_tenant_id} --network 3 --subnet 3 --port 3 -- --floatingip 3 --router 3
```

- `your_tenant_id` is the project tenant id
- When updating the limits for an L3 resource such as, router or floating IP. You have to put an additional -- before

The above guide you to the proccess of updating quotas after you have create the networks. Since in your question you mentioned 'during installation', to update the default quotas you need to change the values in `neutron.conf`.